# Singular Spectrum: Criterion

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a Hamiltonian:
$$H:\mathcal{D}(H)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad H=H^*$$

And its spectral measure:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad H=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$$

Denote its resolvent:
$$R(z):=(z-H)^{-1}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

And singular spectrum:
$$\sigma_\perp(H):=\sigma(H_\perp):=\sigma(J_\perp^*HJ_\perp)$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$\|\chi\|:=\|\chi_\lambda\|_{\lambda\in\Lambda}:=\sup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\|\chi_\lambda\|$$

Regard an open subset:
$$\Delta\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}):\quad\Delta=\Delta^\circ$$

That bounds resolvent:
$$\|\langle R(s+i\varepsilon)\varphi,\varphi\rangle\|_{s\in\Delta}^{|\varepsilon|<1}<\infty\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{H})$$

> Then it is regular:
>   $$\sigma_\perp(H)\cap\Delta=\varnothing$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: Please avoid too many edits unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it...*

**Preparation**

By reducibility one has:
$$\sigma_\perp(H)\cap\Delta=\varnothing\iff E_\perp(\Delta)=0\iff P_\perp E(\Delta)=0$$

For the Borel measures:
$$\nu_{E(\Delta)\varphi}(A)=\langle E(A\cap\Delta)\varphi,\varphi\rangle=\nu_\varphi(A\cap\Delta)$$

> So one must check that:
>   $$\lambda(N)=0\implies\nu_\varphi(N\cap\Delta)=0$$

**Construction**

Denote for readability:
$$R_\Delta^\varphi:=\|\langle R(s+i\varepsilon)\varphi,\varphi\rangle\|_{s\in\Delta}^{|\varepsilon|<1}<\infty$$

By regularity one finds:
$$N\cap\Delta\subseteq U_\varepsilon\subseteq\Delta:\quad\lambda(U_\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$$

By second countability:*
$$U_\varepsilon=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\overline{B_k}:\quad B_k\cap B_{k'}\stackrel{k\neq k'}{=}\varnothing$$

By Stone's formula one has:
$$\langle E(\overline{B_k})\varphi,\varphi\rangle\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}R_\Delta^\varphi\lambda(\overline{B_k})=\frac{1}{2\pi}R_\Delta^\varphi\lambda(B_k)$$

Summing all these up gives:
$$\nu_\varphi(N\cap\Delta)\leq\langle E(U_\varepsilon)\varphi,\varphi\rangle\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\langle E(\overline{B_k})\varphi,\varphi\rangle\\
\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}R_\Delta^\varphi\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda(B_k)=\frac{1}{2\pi}R_\Delta^\varphi\lambda(U_\varepsilon)<\frac{1}{2\pi}R_\Delta^\varphi\varepsilon$$

Concluding the assertion.

**Real line: Disjunction gives intervals!*